# Github actions can't install python packages from requirements.txt

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to build a docker image from a repo. I want to install my packages from my requirements.txt. everything is fine just when it comes to install requirements from requirements.txt file it giving me this error :

```
 > [7/7] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt:
#12 0.545 ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

i know that the problem here because its not finding the requirement file so, i think i need to locate it rightly, if my app code inside a folder into the repo looks like this : repo/app < here is my application files with requirement.txt and dockerfile. so how to setting the right path here ? this is my one :

```
  name: Build and push
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
    with:
      context: .
      file: ./app/Dockerfile
      push: true
      tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}/python:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like inside your dockerfile you need to copy the requirements.txt file to inside the image then run the install command

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY local_directory/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```